# Can you get to the final message?

Tags: riddle, cipher, affix-riddle

I am unsure of the difficulty of this puzzle, but feel free to give it a try

> My prefix is almost dissolved
> My infix is an array
> My suffix forms nouns of action
> I am the key
>
> ---
>
> dpszugweijr

Since it's been a day...
Hint 1:

> Fool you once, shame on me.
>  Fool you 13 times, shame on you.

Hint 2:

> 1 + 1 = *2*

Hint 3:

> *I am the key* is still part of the puzzle

---

##### Edit

I apologize to anyone who tried solving this and was unable to decrypt the message. At the time, I had used an encoder that I believed to work, but upon returning to this site and this question, it appears that it in fact did not work properly, and the cipher text was incorrect. It has now been fixed. I apologize again to anyone who fell short simply due to the last part.

Comment: That's actually a nice way to confirm if the answer you're thinking of is undoubtebly correct. (apart from possible brute-force / dictionary attacks, of course)

Comment: *I solved it* using a dictionary attack, so I'm leaving it open for anyone who likes riddles. I don't recommend stacking two ciphers for this kind of thing, though. Feels guessy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the riddle is

> **SOLUTION**

My prefix is almost dissolved

> **SOLUT** is almost close to the word *Solute* - which can be dissolved in any solution.

My infix is an array

> **LUT** - [Lookup Table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) is an *array* that replaces runtime computation with a simpler array indexing operation.

My suffix forms nouns of action

> **ION** is generally used in nouns related to action like TRANSITION, MOTION, REACTION. Action has "ion" as well.

I am the key

> Solution can also be called as a "key".

Now,

> Apply the key *Solution* to the cipher text which is encrypted using Vigenere cipher, we get *lbhfbyirqvg* and applying Rot13(clued in hints) to this we get **YOUSOLVEDIT**

Final answer

> **You solved it.**

Comment: Really glad to see this riddle be solved after so much time, nice job!

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 Yeah, 2 years is a really loooooong time :)